# Reflection PropertyInfo GetValue call errors out for Collection<> type property

Tags: .net, exception, reflection

I have a propertyInfo object and I try to do a GetValue using it.

```
object source = mysourceObject //This object has a property "Prop1" of type Collection<>.

var propInfo = source.GetType().GetProperty("Prop1");

var propValue = prop.GetValue(this, null);

// do whatever with propValue
// ...
```

I get error at the GetValue() call as "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"

"Prop1" is a plain property declared as Collection.

prop.PropertyType = {Name = "Collection`1" FullName = "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[Application1.DummyClass, Application1, Version=1.5.5.5834, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=628b2ce865838339]]"} System.Type {System.RuntimeType}

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the property value for `source`, not `this` :

```
var propValue = prop.GetValue(source, null);
```